# Construct a new record instances when the Record type has dependent binders in Coq

Tags: record, coq

I intended to construct a new vector instance of Type Vector in the following code. However, initially, the Vector Record type has dependent ident binders. Like the second `ident binder' or the second field -- 'proof' was dependent on the first`ident binder' -- 'mpOf'. When I try to define the subtraction of two mass points, I find it impossible to pass the coq kernel.

```
Require Export Coq.Reals.Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.

Definition Point:= Type.

Record massPoint: Type := cons{number: R; point: Point}.

Definition isVector (v:massPoint) := exists A B : Point, v = add_MP(cons (-1) A)(cons 1 B).

Record Vector : Type := vecCons { mpOf : massPoint ; proof : isVector mpOf}.

Variable sub_MP: massPoint -> massPoint -> massPoint.


Definition point_sub (p1 p2: massPoint):Vector:=
vecCons (sub_MP p1 p2) proof (sub_MP p1 p2). (* errorsome definition*)
```

Anyone has any idea on how to define the point_sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having basic instantiation problems with regards on what a proof is. See for example this code and try to understand what you are missing:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.

Definition Point := Type.
Record massPoint: Type := cons { number: R; point: Point}.

Variable add_MP: massPoint -> massPoint -> massPoint.
Variable sub_MP: massPoint -> massPoint -> massPoint.

Definition isVector (v : massPoint) :=
  exists A B : Point, v = add_MP (cons (-1) A) (cons 1 B).

Record Vector : Type := vecCons { mpOf : massPoint; proof : isVector mpOf }.

Definition point_sub (p1 p2: massPoint) : Vector.
Proof.
refine (vecCons (sub_MP p1 p2) _).
repeat eexists.
```

Comment: It looks like Coq cannot find the supporting mass point A and B. So I think it should be `Definition point_sub (p1 p2: massPoint) : Vector := 
vecCons (sub_MP p1 p2) add_MP (cons (-1) (point p1))(cons 1 (point p2)).` But coq kernel is still complaining `while it is expected to have type
 "isVector (sub_MP p1 p2)".` I feel like I don't have enough commands in my proof repertoire to tackle it. Or I didn't understand your hint well enough. If possible, could you please elaborate a bit? Much appreciate your way of giving hints.

Comment: You need to find ?A ?B such that `  sub_MP p1 p2 =
  add_MP {| number := -1; point := ?A |} {| number := 1; point := ?B |}` The way you write the above term doesn't make sense to the Coq typer, you are expected to write a term with the above type.

Comment: Honestly, the syntax is exactly the help I need. I can’t figure out how to write it in a way that Coq understands. I still lack the knowledge of it. If you decide to write it out, would you please also explain why the syntax is written that way? I want to understand the connections.

Comment: You need to prove `Lemma my_proof : exists A B,  sub_MP p1 p2 = add_MP {| number := -1; point := A |} {| number := 1; point := B |}`, then you can use `my_proof` in the construction of your record. But I'd say you need to take a course in Coq first, so you learn the basic syntax and typing rules first.

Comment: Thanks for the further hint.  I'm able to construct that new record using the following syntax`Definition mp_sub (p1 p2: massPoint) : Vector:=
vecCons (sub_MP p1 p2) (mp_proof p1 p2).`